# How to access installed apps through browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

1password's chrome extension checks to see if the app is installed on your desktop before you can actually do anything.

I was wondering on how could I implement something similar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably implemented using the [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API.

Alternatively, the app can simply have a web server / websockets server open on the local machine, but it would mean the connection will only work while the app is *running*.